# Having trouble on a Scripting Exercise for Unity and deleting objects (So close!!)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, scripting

EDIT: I have updated the code, but it still doesn't quite work properly.

I am almost done with this project but am stuck on the last part.

Basically, the parameters for what I'm working on is as follows:

1. Instantiate one cube prefab every frame into the scene.
2. The cubes need to be named as “Cube1”, “Cube2”… based on the order they are generated.
3. The cubes need to be generated at a random locations within 1 unit from the origin [0,0,0].
4. Each cube should have a random color.
5. The cube size (localScale) shrink 10% in each frame.
6. When the cube’s scale is less than 10% of its original scale, the cube is destroyed.

I am stuck on six. The cubes are created, colored and named, and shrink over time, but will not always destroy themselves after they shrink enough.
I've gotten them to delete SOME of the cubes, but others will now just stop shrinking and stay in the scene indefinitely.

if this helps, I noticed that after it deletes a certain element (cube0 for example)it will reuse that name again and then the list of objects gets all messed up looking and things stop deleting.

My code so far:

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 origin;
    private List<GameObject> cubeList;
    public float targetScale = 0.1f;
    public float shrinkSpeed = 0.1f;
    GameObject newCube;
// Start is called before the first frame update




private void Awake()
{
    cubeList = new List<GameObject>();
}

void Start()
{
    origin = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    AddNewCube();
    for (int i = 0; i < cubeList.Count; i++)
    {
        cubeList[i].name = "cube" + i;
        cubeList[i].transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(cubeList[i].transform.localScale, new Vector3(targetScale, targetScale, targetScale), Time.deltaTime * shrinkSpeed);
        if (cubeList[i].transform.localScale.x <= targetScale + 0.5f)
        {
            cubeList.RemoveAt(i);
            RemoveCube(newCube);
            print("cube " + i + " removed");

        }
    }
}

private void SetRandCubeState(GameObject cube)
{

    float randScale = Random.Range(0.8f, 1.0f);
    Vector3 randomScaler = new Vector3(randScale, randScale, randScale);
    cube.transform.localScale = randomScaler;
    Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(origin.x - 1.0f, origin.x + 1.0f), Random.Range(origin.y - 1.0f, origin.y + 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f,1.0f));
    cube.transform.localPosition = randomPosition;
    Renderer render = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    render.material.SetColor("_Color", Random.ColorHSV());

}

private void AddNewCube()
{
    GameObject newCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    cubeList.Add(newCube);
    SetRandCubeState(newCube);
    


}

private void RemoveCube(GameObject oldCube)
{
    Destroy(oldCube);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Note that the tasks says nothing about a random initial scale. It further says the cubes should destroy after reaching `< 10%` of the original scale. So **if** you use random initial scale then you would also need to store the original scale somewhere.

It also says the cube should shrink `10% each frame` not based on seconds. So how I understand it the first frame it goes `1` -> `0.9`, the second frame it goes `0.9` -> `0.81` etc so either the task is bad formulated or you are doing something else ^^

`Lerp` takes a factor between `0` and `1` and linear interpolates the start and end value accordingly. You are using it wrong ^^

Given an e.g. 60 frames per second you are all the time interpolating between the current scale and `0.1` with a (more or less constant) factor of about `0.0017` .. your cubes will barely scale down and get slower and slower the closer you get to the target. Definitely not scaling down `10 %` **per frame** ;) You are also lerping against the value `0.1` instead of `0`. So your threshold might **never** be reached at all or only very very slow.

Also the cubes should be named accordingly to the order they are created in -> you shouldn't iterate through the list and rename them.

```
// Store existing cube references together with their minimum scale
// before getting destroyed
private Dictionary<Transform, float> cubes = new Dictionary<Transform, float>();

// Count created objects for correct naming
private int cubeSpawnCounter;

void Update()
{
    AddNewCube();

    foreach(var kvp in cubes)
    {
        // Scale down 10% per frame
        kvp.Key.localScale *= 0.9f;

        // Check if reached below threshold of 10% of original scale
        if (kvp.Key.localScale.x <= kvp.Value)
        {
            RemoveCube(kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}

private void SetRandCubeState(GameObject cube)
{
    // Multiply the vector that saves you a lot of typing ;)
    cube.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * Random.Range(0.8f, 1.0f);

    // storing the origin is redundant
    cube.localPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f,1.0f));

    // Only go via the Shader properties if really necessary
    var render = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    render.material.color = Random.ColorHSV());
}

private void AddNewCube()
{
    var newCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);

    SetRandCubeState(newCube);

    // Count the created cubes and set the name ONCE
    cubeSpawnCounter++;
    newCube.name = $"Cube{cubeSpawnCounter}";

    // store the destroy threshold for each cube (10% of original scale)
    cubes[newCube.transform] = randomScale * 0.1f;
}

private void RemoveCube(Transform oldCube)
{
    // Remove from the Dictionary
    cubes.RemoveKey(oldCube);
    print($"{oldCube.name} removed");
    Destroy(oldCube.gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the value never reaches .1 due to the lerp. You could try adding a float to the conditional check (I used a large number, but using .01f could work depending on your use case)

```
if(cubeList[i].transform.localScale.x <= targetScale + .3f) 
{
    cubeList.RemoveAt(i);
    RemoveCube(newCube);
    print("cube " + i + " removed");

}
```

Comment: This got it to work, sort of. Now the cube's won't always delete, but get to a certain point and stop shrinking.

Comment: @SterlingWest Make a prefab put a script that handle the cube logic for each cube. Improve the scope, your script is called cubecreator, but the class is making other job that is not implicit in the scope of that class.
Also you are removing a item from a list while you are runing a loop with that list. 
Thats why each cube need his own Monobehaviur that handle the updates, When the cube is destroyed from his own class need to call cube creator to be remove from the list. Also i dont understand why you want to change the name of the cubes all the time

Comment: I only have to change the name that way because it was assigned in class to me that way. I don't really understand it either lol.

Comment: This is just wrong. All this does is destroying the cubes with scale `0.4` instead of `0.1` ...

Comment: Ah yeah, read the "but using .01f ... "
 I used .3f as an extreme example, so he didn't have to wait so long to see things delete.  I wanted to point out that his code never executed because of the lerp.